# Parse.com Cloud Code not sending Push Notifications

Tags: parse-platform

I am currently running Parse Server 2.2.18 on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am attempting to use Cloud Code to send push notifications from an afterSave function to a particular channel. However, these notifications do not reach any devices even though they succeed.

This is the _PushStatus entry generated by Parse in my MongoDB database...

```
{
    "_id": "eEaI2eReAi",
    "pushTime": "2016-09-06T18:29:01.172Z",
    "_created_at": {
        "$date": "2016-09-06T18:29:01.172Z"
    },
    "query": "{\"channels\":{\"$in\":[\"E22\"]}}",
    "payload": "{\"alert\":\"Test Group - Aye.\",\"e\":\"e\",\"badge\":\"Increment\"}",
    "source": "rest",
    "status": "pending",
    "numSent": 0,
    "pushHash": "675bcfb564807cdfc24085528c2cac39",
    "_wperm": [],
    "_rperm": []
}
```

Push notifications are sent properly through the Web UI on the Parse.com dashboard, where I can target a particular audience with the push of a button. The issue lies within my hosted Parse Server and it talking to APNS. I have correctly configured my push certificates and initialized my Node.js Parse Server with the local .p12 file and application bundle.

Any support is greatly appreciated.

-

**Specifications:**

Shared MongoDB cluster running Mongo 3.0.12.

Parse Server running 2.2.18 on AWS EB.

Comment: Are you trying to send it from the client or from your cloud codee?

Comment: Trying to send from Cloud Code using Parse.Push.send() ...